# create script to insert seed data into mongodb in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm using mongoose and node.js (express), and I wish to insert seed data using script. Like when I do node scripts/createNotifications.js I can insert a data into my db.

My code

```
//createNotifications.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Notification = require('../api/models/notificationModel')
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise

module.exports = (async () => {

    try {

        const new_notification = await new Notification({ 
            "userId" : mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5a3e76ce914e1d1bd854451d"),
            "msg" : "Something"
        }).save()

    } catch(e) {
        console.log('Error creating notifications. ', e)
    }
})()
```

When I run the code I don't see any data been inserted.  I have my server started in port 3000, do I have to connect to mongodb too in this file? since this file has nothing to do with my express app, it's just a separated file.

Comment: where are you calling this method ? have you made connection with db ?

Comment: When you run what code? All that is here is a module declaration with an assigned IIFE. This code itself is not executable. I think really you don't actually mean to assign to the `module.exports` and are simply doing "rote copy" because you don't really know what that means. Also of course. No connection attempt at all

Comment: @GeorgeBailey nope, I run it in my terminal.

Comment: @NeilLunn if I do a http request it will execute.

Comment: "Connection to the **database**". You need to call `mongoose.connect()` in order to do anything. The code here does nothing without that.

Comment: you'll have to `require(path/to/createNotifications)` in your main file and call the method if yow want to see it running

Comment: yeah it's working now when I include the connection to my db, thanks @GeorgeBailey!

Comment: Cool. let me post that as an answer so you can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see this `module` running make sure the following

1. Make sure you've made connection with the database like `mongoose.connect('mongodb://IP/DBName')`
2. What you've posted above is just a module definition. It won't execute on its own. You'll have to `require` this module in your mail file, the file you're running with `node` for example `node server.js` and call the method. Something like

   ```
   var notification = require(path/to/createNotifications);
   notification();
   ```